# FIFO error: can't find control signal - VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga, fifo

I've found a VHDL FIFO code and tryed to modify it to use with two different clocks, one for write and one for read.
I've tryed the code and seems to work in simulation, but when I try to synthesize it I get this error:

> "Can't find control signal for Full"

```
library IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity FIFO is
    Generic (
        constant DATA_WIDTH  : positive := 8;
        constant FIFO_DEPTH : positive := 100
    );
    Port ( 
        WCLOCK      : in  STD_LOGIC;
        RCLOCK      : in  STD_LOGIC;
        WriteEn : in  STD_LOGIC;
        DataIn  : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (DATA_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
        ReadEn  : in  STD_LOGIC;
        DataOut : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (DATA_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
        Empty   : out STD_LOGIC;
        Full    : out STD_LOGIC;
        ModuleRESET : in STD_LOGIC
    );
end FIFO;

architecture FIFO_archi of FIFO is
    type FIFO_Memory is array (0 to FIFO_DEPTH - 1) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (DATA_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
    signal Memory : FIFO_Memory;
    signal Head : natural range 0 to FIFO_DEPTH - 1;
    signal Tail : natural range 0 to FIFO_DEPTH - 1;


    begin
         -- Memory Pointer Process
        process (WCLOCK, RCLOCK, ModuleRESET)
            variable Looped : boolean;
        begin
            if ModuleRESET = '0' then
                Head <= 0;
                Tail <= 0;
                Looped := false;
                Full  <= '0';
                Empty <= '1';
                DataOut <= (others => '0');
            elsif ReadEn = '1' then
                if rising_edge(RCLOCK) then                    
                    if ((Looped = true) or (Head /= Tail)) then
                        -- Update data output
                        DataOut <= Memory(Tail);

                        -- Update Tail pointer as needed
                        if (Tail = FIFO_DEPTH - 1) then
                            Tail <= 0;
                            Looped := false;
                            else
                                Tail <= Tail + 1;
                            end if;
                        end if;
                    end if;
                -- Update Empty and Full flags
                if (Head = Tail) then
                    if Looped then
                        Full <= '1';
                        else
                            Empty <= '1';
                        end if;
                    else
                        Empty   <= '0';
                        Full    <= '0';
                end if;
            elsif WriteEn = '1' then
                if rising_edge(WCLOCK) then   
                        if ((Looped = false) or (Head /= Tail)) then
                            -- Write Data to Memory
                            Memory(Head) <= DataIn;

                            -- Increment Head pointer as needed
                            if (Head = FIFO_DEPTH - 1) then
                                Head <= 0;
                                Looped := true;
                            else
                                Head <= Head + 1;
                            end if;
                        end if;
                -- Update Empty and Full flags
                if (Head = Tail) then
                    if Looped then
                        Full <= '1';
                        else
                            Empty <= '1';
                        end if;
                    else
                        Empty   <= '0';
                        Full    <= '0';
                end if;
                end if;
            end if;
        end process;

end FIFO_archi;
```

How I can solve this error?

Comment: You can't do that. A FIFO with a different clk for read and write is very different from a simple FIFO with one clock. You have to do pointers resynchronization using gray counter logic, which may be out of your comfort zone. Every synthesis tool has IP cores for dual-clock FIFO, why don't you use it instead?

Comment: Indeed. You cannot just modify a single clock FIFO and expect it to become a CDC FIFO. 
A clock domain crossing is a very different beast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to modify a single clock FIFO to become a clock domain crossing FIFO is no easy task. They are two very different beasts.

I have attempted to draw a block diagram of the simplest possible clock domain crossing FIFO design. Excuse the crudity of my freehand drawing skills. My example is a 16 Byte FIFO, but it can be expanded to arbitrary depth and width, as long as the depth is a power of two.

I have used a blue marker to highlight all signals where vendor specific attributes to protect against synthesis optimization must be applied.

There are no shortcuts. If you want to create your own clock domain crossing FIFO, then this block diagram represents the bare minimum you must do.

[image: CDC FIFO block diagram]

Answer (score 0):

Inferring a FIFO with a single clock for read and write is generally straightforward, regardless of the toolset. Inferring a FIFO with separate clocks for read and write can be tricky, dependent on the hardware that you are targeting and the tool that you are using to synthesize the HDL.

Start by checking in the manual / userguide for your synthesis tool to ensure that it supports inferring FIFOs with separate read/write clocks. If it does, it will likely suggest a supported HDL behavioral description that you should model your code after.

Very frequently a problem is describing the FIFO with a single process with two clocks. Typically doing this infers a register that is sensitive to two clocks -- which hardware does not support, and thus causes an error. Without more specific information regarding tools, a more specific answer will be guessing.

Comment: I have two module, one that write a FIFO and another, when FIFO is full, start to read from FIFO. So I have two different clock and when I write FIFO I will not read data and when I read FIFO I will not write data on it so a pointer or clock collide will never happen. Another solution is use a module that have two input clock and 1 output clock. But this will create same problems with clock collide?

Comment: @Yaro When you are writing or reading the FIFO has nothing to do with the clocks that the FIFO utilizes. Are these clocks truely independent? Do they need to be? For example, they are generated from completely independent clock sources, which are not related in any way (i.e. separate oscillators)?  If you don't need truly independent clocks, then use a common clock. That would be describing a synchronous FIFO instead of an asynchronous FIFO. Synchronous FIFO is much easier to implement.